# How to use preposition "like" in a question?

Tags: questions, prepositional-phrases, syntax

Which one is correct: What was the weather like in Toronto?" or "What was the weather in Toronto like?"

Comment: That's an excellent answer @FumbleFingers. Why not make it one, instead of just a comment?

Comment: I noticed a couple of misleading "typos" in my previous, so duly fixed and posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just a stylistic choice whether to put the preposition ***like*** immediately after the "head" noun ***weather*** in the full noun phrase being queried *(**the weather in Toronto**)*, OR move it to the end of that noun phrase.

But stylistically it would be a very bad choice to move ***like*** to the end of a longer noun phrase, such as...

> ***?** What was the weather in Toronto yesterday afternoon at 5 o'clock after you finished work like?*
> (Where the *initial* question mark is a linguistic convention for "questionable, unlikely".)

In *that* case, the only sensible option is to introduce ***like*** somewhere earlier. Ideally after ***weather*** -  it could reasonably be "delayed" until after ***Toronto***, but the further it is from the "head" noun, the harder it becomes to parse.